# Missing variable in $_SESSION while dealing with OAuth2

Tags: php, session, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I am trying to do a login based on gitlab OAuth2.

So I've found this [package](https://github.com/omines/oauth2-gitlab) which is based on league/oauth2-client and this package seems to undercover all my needs. I properly configured token on my gitlab and it logins me properly, but when I got a redirection after sign in I got invalid state, which is caused by missing `$_SESSION['oauth2state']`

So the workflow is like this:

Go to localhost:XXXX --> Be redirected to gitlab --> Sign in --> Redirect back to localhost:XXXX --> Get invalid state because missing variable in session

My code is based on snippet from [that](https://github.com/omines/oauth2-gitlab#authorization-code-flow)

My PHP script

```
$provider = new Gitlab([
    'clientId'          => $application_id,
    'clientSecret'      => $secret,
    'redirectUri'       => $redirect_uri,
    'domain'            => $domain
]);

$options = [
    'state' => $unique_hash,
    'scope' => ['read_user','api']
];

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    ob_start(); // debug
    var_dump($_SESSION); // debug --> Here I have a variable
    error_log(ob_get_clean(), 4); // debug
    header('Location: '.$authUrl);
    exit;

// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    ob_start(); // debug
    var_dump($_SESSION); // debug --> Here I get null
    error_log(ob_get_clean(), 4); // debug
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');

} else {
     // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the problem is you never create a session. That's the reason why `$_SESSION` is `null`.

So how i manage that is that i always create a session with

```php
if(empty(session_id()) {
  session_start()
}
```

(This needs to be called everytime someone "visits" your website. Means, every `.php` file. Best approach would be to put it into a `config.php`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I was thinking that this package handle session by themselves